# unable to use selectors of ngxs in service gives null/undefined

Tags: angular, observable, state, ngxs

I am using ngxs in angular app. One selector is working fine which I am using for canActivate. when I tried to get token or id from selectors it does not works.

**state**

```
export class AuthStateModel {
  id: number;
  first_name: string;
  last_name: string;
  api_access_token: string;
  email: string;
}

@State<AuthStateModel>({
  name: "auth",
  defaults: {
    id: null,
    first_name: null,
    last_name: null,
    api_access_token: null,
    email: null,
  },
})
@Injectable()
export class AuthState {
  @Selector()
  static isAuthenticated(state: AuthStateModel) : boolean {
    console.log('selector token status',!!state.api_access_token);
    return !!state.api_access_token;
  }
  @Selector()
  static getToken(state: AuthStateModel) : string {
    console.log('selector token ',state.api_access_token);
    return state.api_access_token;
  }
  @Selector()
  static getLoggedId(state: AuthStateModel) : number {
    console.log('selector id ',state.id);
    return state.id;
  }
 

  constructor(private loginService: AuthService) {}

  @Action(Login)
  login({ patchState }: StateContext<AuthStateModel>, { payload }: Login) {
    console.log('email',payload.email);
    console.log('password',payload.password);
    return this.loginService.login(payload.email, payload.password).pipe(
      tap(
        (result) => {
          console.log('result',result);
          patchState({
            id: result.data.id,
            first_name: result.data.first_name,
            last_name: result.data.last_name,
            email: result.data.email,
            api_access_token: result.data.api_access_token,
          });
        },
      ),
      catchError((err) => {
        console.log('err',err);
        return throwError(`Invalid username or password`);
      })
    );
  }

}
```

**auth.guard**

```
  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    const isAuthenticated = this.store.selectSnapshot(AuthState.isAuthenticated);
    if (!isAuthenticated) {
     // this.router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url } });
     this.openConfirmationDialog(route);
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
```

**user service**

```
 token;
  loggedId;


  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private store: Store
  ) {
    this.token = this.store.select(AuthState.getToken);
    this.loggedId = this.store.select(AuthState.getLoggedId);
  
  }

GetNotifications() {
    console.log('user service token',this.token);
    console.log('user service id',this.loggedId);
}
```

selector `isAuthenticated` works in canActivate but somehow selectors `getToken` , `getLoggedId` not gives proper values when I use in user service.

Whats going wrong? pls help and guide

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet

```
const isAuthenticated = !!this.store.selectSnapshot(state => state.auth.api_access_token);
```

You might also want to use state tokens

```
const AUTH_STATE_TOKEN = new StateToken<AuthStateModel>('auth');

@State<AuthStateModel>({
  name: AUTH_STATE_TOKEN,
  defaults: {
    id: null,
    first_name: null,
    last_name: null,
    api_access_token: null,
    email: null,
  },
})
```

With state tokens you can do something like this

```
const isAuthenticated = !!this.store.selectSnapshot(AUTH_STATE_TOKEN).api_access_token;
```

Select snapshot docs: https://www.ngxs.io/advanced/token

State token docs: https://www.ngxs.io/advanced/token

Comment: I am getting `isAuthenticated`  value from my code but not getting proper values from `getToken` and `getLoggedId` selectors. could you please let me know what's going wrong?

Comment: for `getToken` try this `this.store.selectSnapshot(AUTH_STATE_TOKEN).api_access_token;` and for `getLoggedId` → `this.store.selectSnapshot(AUTH_STATE_TOKEN).id;`